# Create 'squared' textbox in which each character goes into each square

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

I want to create a customized textbox in which the textbox consists of squares. When we type in the textbox, each character goes into each square. This type of textboxes can be seen in Bank cheque to input account number. I want to create such a textbox in windows form.How can I do this?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question, just given a statement. Id imagine this is done through multiple textboxes and text entry events

Comment: @Sayse Only using multiple textboxes. If there are 30 characters, do i need to put 30 textboxes together for this?

Comment: This is common requirement. So, is there any better alternatives?

Comment: Is it web, Windows Forms, WPF ... ?

Comment: You haven't really given much information to go on, but enter text into textbox 1 if entry is greater than x amount of characters, overflow into textbox 2 etc

Comment: on every key press get the value and generate dynamic textbox and pass value to it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, You can try using Third Party Vendor's **Masked TextBox** instead of creating individual textboxes for each number.

Here is one of such vendors link : http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/wpf/tools/documents/promptchar.htm

You can also check other leading third party Masked TextBox control set from, DX, Telerik, Xceed, et al